# Setting Multiple chart series datasource for a Kendo chart through JQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Chart defined on my cshtml page as below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<MyModel>()
        .Name("chart")
        .Title("")
        .Legend(legend => legend
            .Visible(false)
        )
        .Series(series =>
         {
                    series.Scatter(model => model.X, model => model.Y);
                    series.Scatter(model => model.X, model => model.Y);
        })
        )
```

I need to set the data of each of these series using a JQuery call. 
My JQuery call and returning data works fine, and the below will populate the first series data:

```
 function GetChartData(ex,ten) {
            var str = "{'arg': '" + ex + "', 'arg2': '" + ten ' }";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Controller/CreateChartData',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: str ,
                success: function (data) {

                    var grid = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
                    grid.dataSource.data(data.ChartData);
                    grid.refresh();

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
```

I am however, unable to set the second series data.
I have tried the following which rendered nothing on the chart:

```
 function GetChartData(ex,ten) {
            var str = "{'arg': '" + ex + "', 'arg2': '" + ten ' }";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Controller/CreateChartData',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: str ,
                success: function (data) {

                    var grid = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
            grid.options.series[0].data = data.ChartData;
           grid.options.series[1].data = data.ChartDataSeries2; 

                    grid.refresh();

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I'm using Kendo UI charts on a couple sites and they can be really picky sometimes. Do you get any js errors while trying to bind two series?

Comment: No, no errors at all. The data is coming back ok, but setting the datasource only sets the first series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you might try, is to not initialize that chart until after you have all the data.

That way instead of calling refresh() you can pass both series to the .kendoChart() method

```
function GetChartData(ex,ten) {
        var str = "{'arg': '" + ex + "', 'arg2': '" + ten ' }";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Controller/CreateChartData',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: str ,
            success: function (data) {

                 $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
                    title: {
                        text: "Example"
                    },
                    legend: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "scatterLine"
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: "series1",
                        data: data.ChartData
                    }, {
                        name: "series2",
                        data: data.ChartDataSeries2
                    }, {
                        name: "series3",
                        data: data.ChartDataSeries3
                    }]
                });
            }

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
```

Working aspx example page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GraphTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="GraphTest" %>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/kendo.metro.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/kendo.kendo.min.css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="/js/libs/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>
```

```
    <div id="example" class="k-content">
        <div class="chart-wrapper">
            <div id="chart"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function createChart() {

                var data1 = [[10, 10], [15, 20], [20, 25], [32, 40], [43, 50], [55, 60], [60, 70], [70, 80], [90, 100]];

                $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
                    title: {
                        text: "Charge current vs. charge time"
                    },
                    legend: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "scatterLine"
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: "0.8C",
                        data: data1
                    }, {
                        name: "1.6C",
                        data: [[10, 40], [17, 50], [18, 70], [35, 90], [47, 95], [60, 100]]
                    }, {
                        name: "3.1C",
                        data: [[10, 70], [13, 90], [25, 100]]
                    }],
                    xAxis: {
                        max: 90,
                        labels: {
                            format: "{0}m"
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: "Time"
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        max: 100,
                        labels: {
                            format: "{0}%"
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: "Charge"
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                        format: "{1}% in {0} minutes"
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // Initialize the chart with a delay to make sure
                    // the initial animation is visible
                    createChart();

                    $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", function (e) {
                        createChart();
                    });
                }, 400);
            });
        </script>
    </div>


</div>
</form>
```

Comment: do you have an example of this, i'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I wrote something up, that's what I was thinking, it might not be 100% since I didn't run it, but will be close.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this with no success. I get no errors, but also get no data shown. The data.ChartData, data.ChartDataSeries2 and data.ChartDataSeries3 collections are all of my own type, so do I need to define which property on my type is the x point and which property is they point? If so, do you know how I do that?

Comment: The data needs to be in a format like this: 

[[10, 10], [15, 20], [20, 25], [32, 40], [43, 50], [55, 60]]

Comment: I have hardcoded the data example in your comment above into my data being returned through the ajax call but still with no luck. No data shows on my chart at all

Comment: Hmm, could you toss some alerts in the success function and post up your data.ChartData object?

Comment: I'll pull up visual studio in a minute and see if I can get the chart to display

Comment: I've alerted the data.ClientData => "[[0.5, 0.4], [0.6, 0.3]]". This should work, shouldn't it

Comment: Decimal values will work fine. 

Please compare your code with the example page I created.

Comment: This works fine, but as soon as I set data1 with "data.ChartData" (hardcoded with exactly the same data as data1) from my jquery call, it no longer works

Comment: It's got to be something with the format the data is being returned in. Could you add in the whole return object to your question. I'm off to lunch but will take a look when i get back

Comment: When looking at the data returned though Chrome developer tools, I can see that the data is being returned as "[[10, 10], [15, 20], [20, 25], [32, 40], [43, 50], [55, 60], [60, 70], [70, 80], [90, 100]]" i.e. it has double quotes at each end. Do you know how I removed them as I believe this to be the issue

Comment: Ya, looks like it's coming back as a string. Wrap it in an eval() and then javascript will know it's an array of data.